# Evaluating $\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \sin x\right)^x$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

Limit of trigonometric function sinx to the power x. Which process is easiest to solve this and how

> $$\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \sin x\right)^x$$

Comment: Where are you getting these questions (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/662029/jency) from?

Comment: You have posted (at last count) four *very similar* questions (limits of "function to a function" expressions), none of which has shown any effort on your part.  You should explain what you have tried and where you got stuck. In your case, you could link to your previous questions and try to convey why you're still struggling with these types of problems. This could prompt answerers to give more-thorough explanations to help you understand. The Math.SE community is here to help you learn, not to do your homework for you.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know the fact. It won't happen again. I will try on my own. And I get stuck I shall tell the point only for understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you mean $x\to 0^+$, because for $x<0$ the expression is not defined for real functions.

Using $\lim_{t\to 0+}t^t = 1$ you get

$$\left(\left( \sin x\right)^{\sin x}\right)^{\frac{x}{\sin x}}\stackrel{x\to 0^+}{\rightarrow}1^1 = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* Change the base to get $$e^{\log{(\sin x)^x}}.$$ Since we approach from above $0,$ it is the case that eventually we would have $\sin x>0,$ so that we may write this expression as $$e^{x\log{\sin x}},$$ and now can you see that as $x\to 0^+,$ we have that the function moves to $1$?